# mounting and accessing Encrypted LVM after reinstallation of Linux

Tags: encryption, mount, lvm, luks

I had Fedora installed on a LVM & had my /home & another file systems in it encrypted. ( i remember the passwords but forgot the cipher protocol used )

Now, I installed Ubuntu without reformatting the /home & /resto expecting that I'll just be able to access them. But, now these partitions & all the data in them aren't accessible.

I've tried different things, as follows.

```
root@ubuntu:~# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x1549f232

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848   268005375   133899264    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       269033470  1929263103   830114817    5  Extended
/dev/sda4      1929263104  1953521663    12129280   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda5       269033472  1929263103   830114816   8e  Linux LVM
```

/dev/sda5 - the LVM is mounted without problems as I have my root partition in there. Of the 5 filesystems in it, I could mount 3 easily as they were not encrypted.

```
root@ubuntu:~# mount

/dev/sda1 on /media/ubuntu/SYSTEM type fuseblk  (rw...)
/dev/mapper/vg_shakti-lv_root on /mnt type ext4 (rw)

root@ubuntu:~# lvscan 
 ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_shakti/lv_data' [300.00 GiB] inherit
 ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_shakti/lv_root' [50.00 GiB] inherit
 ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_shakti/lv_softs' [84.22 GiB] inherit
 ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_shakti/lv_resto' [97.66 GiB] inherit
 ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_shakti/lv_home' [259.78 GiB] inherit
```

Out of these, the filesystems resto & home are encrypted & are not accessible. the others I could just mount and use !

```
root@ubuntu:~# ls -al /dev/mapper/
 total 0
 drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     160 Jun 25  2014 .
 drwxr-xr-x 16 root root    4520 Jun 25 09:54 ..
 crw-------  1 root root 10, 236 Jun 25  2014 control
 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Jun 25  2014 vg_shakti-lv_data -> ../dm-0
 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Jun 25  2014 vg_shakti-lv_home -> ../dm-4
 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Jun 25 09:42 vg_shakti-lv_resto -> ../dm-3
 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Jun 25  2014 vg_shakti-lv_root -> ../dm-1
 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Jun 25  2014 vg_shakti-lv_softs -> ../dm-2

root@ubuntu:~# blkid 
 /dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs" 
 /dev/sda1: LABEL="SYSTEM" UUID="E29C40B19C4081D1" TYPE="ntfs" 
 /dev/sda2: LABEL="HP" UUID="FA047C07047BC563" TYPE="ntfs" 
 /dev/sda4: UUID="0d60e335-934b-4abd-a82c-1b5dcd46a5b6" TYPE="swap" 
 /dev/sda5: UUID="fotWMV-2dRn-rwFI-BiyC-rbE9-3VX1-0i429A" TYPE="LVM2_member" 
 /dev/sr0: LABEL="Ubuntu 14.04 LTS amd64" TYPE="iso9660" 
 /dev/mapper/vg_shakti-lv_data: UUID="9d5e8ed9-c709-48df-a019-b27db1b0aa12" TYPE="ext4" 
 /dev/mapper/vg_shakti-lv_root: UUID="74b95b0d-d2b5-4e5e-b33b-ebc77375180c" TYPE="ext4" 
 /dev/mapper/vg_shakti-lv_softs: UUID="56e531f4-3521-4970-af73-e8ef03367c42" TYPE="ext4"
```

Don't know why the other 2 filesystems are not recognized as block devices.

**Now, my tries for accessing the encrypted ones using cryptsetup**

```
root@ubuntu:~# modprobe dm-crypt
root@ubuntu:~# modprobe dm-mod

root@ubuntu:~#  cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sda5 
Device /dev/sda5 is not a valid LUKS device.

root@ubuntu:~# cryptsetup luksDump /dev/dm-4
Device /dev/dm-4 is not a valid LUKS device.
```

or

```
root@ubuntu:~# cryptsetup luksDump /dev/mapper/vg_shakti-lv_home 
Device /dev/mapper/vg_shakti-lv_home is not a valid LUKS device.
```

Weird, as surely it was encrypted & I was typing the passwords during every boot ! So, it's not even being recognized as a LUKS device. How to tell the kernel these are encrypted filesystems ?

Now, how do I set up so as to be able to access my encrypted partitions ? Do i need to define some partition tables separately ?

```
There is no /etc/crypttab as of now.
```

Please tell me the commands to get this setup done properly (with those to test & identify the encrypted filesystems)

(note: these are outputs while am running a liveCD of the 14.04 LTS)

Answer (score 0):

sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/by-uuid/$(uuid of respective LV crypts) foo then;
sudo mount /dev/mapper/foo-bar /$mntpt

then to fix or in place tweak crypt use  cryptsetup-rencrypt  (not installed by default)  this assumes you know ALL passphrases or keyfiles  OLD cipher  is NOT required only the new desired one